# How to populate an Excel sheet with the data from an arraylist using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, apache-poi

How to populate an Excel sheet with the data from an arraylist using Apache POI?

```
public String exporttoexcel(UserDetails user) throws Exception {

    System.out.print("Inside serviceimpl.ExportToExcel method");
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)0);

        List<UserDetails> lstUserDetail = getUserDetailList();

        for (int i=0; i<lstUserDetail.size(); i++) {

            UserDetails lstUserDetail1 = lstUserDetail.get(i);

            String a=lstUserDetail1.getStrUserName();
             System.out.print("useridddd is"+a);

             HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
                cell.setCellValue(lstUserDetail1.getStrUserId());
                cell.setCellValue(lstUserDetail1.getStrUserName());
                cell.setCellValue(lstUserDetail1.getStrEMail());
                cell.setCellValue(lstUserDetail1.getStrUserStatus());
                cell.setCellValue(lstUserDetail1.getStrUserRole());

         }
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();

       System.out.print("file created");

       return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created one single cell and entering all the values in a same single cell each time.

You need to take two loops. One for iterating through row and another for iterating through column. Though I have not tested... use code like below.

```
 for(int RowNum=0; RowNum<MaxArrayLength;RowNum++){
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(RowNum);
    for(int ColNum=0; ColNum<ArrayWidth;ColNum++){
        HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(ColNum);
        cell.setCellValue(ArrayList[RowNum][ColNum]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: how to find the arraylist width ?

Comment: Arraylist Width is basically the dimension. If you are using one dimension Arraylist then no need to give first for loop. In this case all of your data will be in single row.

Comment: i have an arraylist which contains id,name,email ids,phone no and there are 50 records for these...then what should i do.

Comment: Keep ArrayMaxLength = 50  (for records) and ArrayWidth = 4 (for id, name, email ids, phoneNo. Start from RowNum =1 because first row (RowNum = 0) you will use for Header I guess.

Comment: all the cells are benig filled with userid only,i want all the values in of id,name,email in different cells in a proper table format.             could you please write the looping part..thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I have made some changes in code. You have to set the values as the Arraylist contents Here ArrayList is the name of Array List.

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing like how can i enable the user to download the excel file created on the server,because it would be created on the server...??

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("your file path");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet name");
            try {

    //creating the headers          
                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue("name");
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name1");                    
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue("name2");

    //get the list which u want
                List<String> list = getNamesList();                         
            int rowNum = 1;
            for (Name name : list ) {
                Row row1 = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        row1.createCell(0).setCellValue((name.get..));

}
                workbook.write(fileOut);
}
```